# jquery ajax response "readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, trackjs

I am getting `"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"` ajax response for making an http request to load json file.

The web page has loaded inside an iframe and there is no code to change the URL within the webpage while making an ajax request.

Here's the Ajax config

```
url: 'some file in the same domain',
method: 'GET',
dataType: 'JSON'
```

I am not able to re-create this situation but this has been logged in trackJS.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: We don't have nearly enough context to find the error, would you mind adding some code?

Comment: imagine the magic it does a ajax but without a url

Comment: Maybe CORS? Just open your Chrome Dev Tools and check what's happening in the Network tab.

Comment: As I have trackjs logging implemented in my application. I can see error logs over there. However, I am not able to reproduce this error.

Comment: @pratiknagariya if you cannot reproduce it, then it doesn't really happen, right? ;)

Comment: @sjahan - I have integrated trackjs into my web application where I can have error logging. So whenever any error occurs on the live application it pushes to trackjs error logs.

Comment: @pratiknagariya that's cool, but it seems it doesn't log enough. Here, we cannot deduct anything just from that.

Answer (score 0):

This signature of Network Error can occur when there is a pending XHR request that is cancelled. The request can be canceled by the browser when the page is closing, or by a browser extension if it has been blocked. For example, if there is an adblocker extension present, some network requests might show up this way.

I'd suggest examining your data in TrackJS to see if the problem is limited to a small subset of users. You may be able to safely ignore this.

As a way to recreate it, you can download an adblocker extension, such as "ublock origin", which can accept custom rules. Add a custom blocking rule for a URL that your application uses, and you should see the error.

You can also use this mechanism to block the same URLs being requested in your TrackJS error reports, and see what the impact is on end users. Make sure you have appropriate fallbacks in case the requests fail and you don't leave the user in a volatile state.